# Why are my MAMP PRO local dev sites slow in Firefox & Chrome?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, localhost, mamp

I can't work out why when viewing local sites that I've given a virtual (.dev) host name to are so slow in Firefox & Chrome... but not in Safari. It takes about 5 seconds to load each page in FF & C... but is absolutely instant every time in Safari.

Does anyone have any ideas I could try. It would be most appreciated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of the above worked but this did!! At last....

To fix, in your hosts file you need to list all your local dev sites in a space delimited row like so...

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localsite1.dev localsite2.dev localsite3.dev
```

Instead of one entry on each line as is the default.

I don't know the technical reason why this works but it does. It's a huge relief after six months of having to debug websites outside of preferred browser.

Comment: Argg! This worked like magic at first. But now my local sites are craaaaawwwwling again. Any idea why this might have worked temporarily?

Comment: I can confirm the same issue and solution worked for me, the original question describes the problem perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and got some speed increase by including ipv6 addresses in /etc/hosts like this:

```
127.0.0.1     6drudev.localhost
::1           6drudev.localhost
fe80::1%lo0   6drudev.localhost
127.0.0.1     7drudev.localhost
::1           7drudev.localhost
fe80::1%lo0   7drudev.localhost
```

YMMV of course.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Given that a go and seems to definitely be better... like the first load of the local site is still veryyyy slow, but then navigating the site after that seems to speed up. Although when I refresh a page it is sometimes very slow to reload again... So, thanks.. any improvement is appreciated.

Comment: What's the PHP memory limit? Try setting it to 512MB (if you have the spare RAM of course). Also install mod_expires as per here: http://metaskills.net/2006/02/19/how-to-control-browser-caching-with-apache-2/ Also enable one of the PHP accelerators e.g. APC (see the bottom of php.ini).

Comment: Also make sure you have the docroot and directories set to have no trailing slash in httpd.conf (no idea why this work but it seems to).

Comment: @MattGibson The PHP tweaks will only help scripts compile faster AFTER the connection is made; it doesn't alleviate this particular problem at all.

Comment: @SoldOutActivist Agreed, but every little helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with IPv6 and OSX; something Apple has acknowledged. You can google this as it's rather prevalent.

One solution which isn't universally effective is not using "local" as part of the custom DNS entry. ".dev" is the typical suggestion, but anything works. In Firefox, this works well, but Chrome still doesn't care.

In Firefox you can disable IPv6, which eliminates the problem entirely for that browser. Go to the URL about:config and in the search box enter "ipv6." There should be a single entry: network.dns.disableIPv6. Enable it. Restart the browswer. Done.

Note that PHPMyAdmin will not like this change. When you go through the MAMP startup page, it'll throw errors. I bypassed that by going straight to the source: http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/. Eventually, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to comprehend why this is happening, as others are clearly more knowledgeable about this than me - see the other answer. However I think I have a fix.

The following methodology solved this problem for me:

1. Open terminal and run "sudo apachectl stop"
2. Change MAMP server ports to "default ports"
3. Enjoy

Explanation:

1. Stops apache from running on the machine. This is needed as we are setting MAMPS ports to the standard apache ports and therefore making a conflict.
2. Change the actual ports

I don't yet now if this will fix the problem indefinitely, but time will tell.